# Evaluate $7^{8^9}\mod 100$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, congruences

I'm preparing myself for discrete math exam and here's one of the preparation problems:

Evaluate $$7^{8^9}\mod 100$$

Here's my solution:
$7^2\equiv49 \mod 100\implies (7^2)^2\equiv49^2=2401\equiv 1\mod 100$

So, as it turns out $7^4\equiv 1\mod 100$. It will be useful later. Now let's examine $8^9\mod 100$.

We have $512=8^3\equiv 12 \mod 100$, so $(8^3)^3\equiv 12^3 = 1728 \equiv 28 \mod 100$. So, as $8^9\equiv 28 \mod 100$, then $8^9=100x+28$ for some natural $x$. So:

$7^{8^9}=7^{100x+28}=7^{100x}7^{28}=(7^4)^{25x}(7^4)^7\equiv 1^{25x}1^7 \equiv 1 \mod 100$

Which means the final answer is that $7^{8^9}\mod 100=1$.

That's my solution, but I'm curious about other ones. Has anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Since $7^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$, you only need to compute $8^9 \pmod{4}$, as opposed to $8^9 \pmod{100}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$7^2\equiv -1\mod 50$, hence $7^4\equiv 1\mod 100$.

Thus $\,7^{8^9}=\bigl(7^8\bigr)^{8^8}=\bigl((7^4)^2\bigr)^{8^8}\equiv 1\mod 100$.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thank you for pointing the error. I was too swift.I corrected the argument, and it's simpler now (requiring paper and pencil for the reader, maybe).

Answer (score 1):

If you know $7^4 = 1 \mod 100$, then since your desired quantity is a power of this $7^4$, you will have that that also is $1 \mod 100$ automatically.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a solution without "magically" discovering that $7^4\equiv 1$

Comment: I'm not sure because you have nested powers, i.e. your power of $7$ is $8^9$. If the power was just something like say, $8$ or $13$ or whatever, then you could use successively squaring starting with $7^1$ to get $7^{2k} \mod 100$ for each $k$ after you write the desired power in binary, and multiply the corresponding powers $7^{2k}$ that have 1's in the binary expansion in the $(k+1)$th place of your desired power. If your desired power of $7$ is $m$, this takes about $\log_2 m$ operations to compute

Answer (score 1):

[Carmichael's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(100) = \text{lcm}(\lambda(25),\lambda(4)) = \text{lcm}(20,2) = 20$.

$7$ is coprime to $100$, so $7^{8^9} \equiv 7^{8^9 \bmod 20} \bmod 100$

$\lambda(20) = \text{lcm}(\lambda(5),\lambda(4)) = \text{lcm}(4,2) = 4$
 and $9 \equiv 1 \bmod 4$

$8$ has a higher exponent than $20$ in $2$, their only shared prime factor, so $8^9 \equiv 8 \bmod 20$

This gives $7^{8^9} \equiv 7^{8^9 \bmod 20} \equiv 7^{8}  \bmod 100$

So we just need to square $7$ three times to get our answer... but when we get to $49^2$ we happily discover that $49^2 = (50-1)^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 100$.

So  $7^{8^9} \equiv 7^{8} \equiv ((7^2)^2)^2 \equiv  (49^2)^2 \equiv 1^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 100$

It's perfectly legitimate, of course, to find out  $7^8 \bmod 100$ first in the hope that it will be something convenient, but this is a method that will work in the absence of good fortune.